# viewController's viewdidload called before appDelegate's method

Tags: ios, macos

I want to initialize some code before my viewDidLoad called , but it always go to viewDidLoad first and then it comes to the method applicationDidFinishLaunching.
I am unable to understand what is going on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my app delegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method all of sudden being called AFTER my RootViewController:viewDidLoad method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853589/why-is-my-app-delegates-didfinishlaunchingwithoptions-method-all-of-sudden-bein)

Comment: can you show code of applicationDidFinishLaunching?

Answer (score 6):

That is because AppDelegate instantiates its window and main view controller automatically before applicationDidFinishLaunching. You should uncheck for "Is Initial View Controller" in your storyboard and manually create window and its root view controller in applicationDidFinishLaunching.

Answer (score 5):

The documentation for [application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html):

> You should use this method to initialize your application and prepare
>   it for running. It is called after your application has been launched
>   and its main nib file has been loaded. At the time this method is
>   called, your application is in the inactive state. At some point after
>   this method returns, a subsequent delegate method is called to move
>   your application to the active (foreground) state or the background
>   state.

So the view is lazily loaded for view controllers once the the view property or method is called. When this happens viewDidLoad is called so if your window rootViewController property is set to your root ViewController in the nib then this is expected behavior.