# Userdefault not working swift

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, xcode8, userdefaults

So I'm having trouble with saving my textfields on USERDEFAULTS. I have managed to use this mehtod on my contacts(as you can see my code below) and when i try to save/load on my textfields in didn't work. can you give me any advice. Thanks

**PBProfile.Swift**

```
class PBProfile {

    var firstName: String = ""
    var lastName: String = ""
    var contacts = [String]()

    func loadFromDefaults() {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        firstName = defaults.string(forKey: "firstName") ?? ""
        lastName = defaults.string(forKey: "lastName") ?? ""
        contacts = defaults.stringArray(forKey: "contacts") ?? [String]()

    }

    func saveToDefaults() {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        defaults.set(firstName, forKey: "firstName")
        defaults.set(lastName, forKey: "lastName")
        defaults.set(contacts, forKey: "contacts")
        defaults.synchronize()
    }

}
```

**AppDelegate**

```
    var profile: PBProfile!
    var location: PBLocation!

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FIRApp.configure()

        profile = PBProfile()
        profile.loadFromDefaults()
        profile.saveToDefaults()

        location = PBLocation()

        return true
   }

}
```

**Settings.swift**

```
import Foundation
import ContactsUI
import Contacts

class Settings: UIViewController, CNContactPickerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    //VARIABLES
    var saveButtonSelected: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var firstName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lastName: UITextField!
    //--- End of Variables --

    // -- ViewDidLoad --
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
        self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()

        firstName.delegate = self
        lastName.delegate = self

        tableView.reloadData()

        firstName.text = app.profile.firstName
        lastName.text = app.profile.lastName

        app.profile.loadFromDefaults()
    }
    //-- End of ViewDidLoad

    //Prepare for segue
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        app.profile.saveToDefaults()

    }


    //MARK -> ADD CONTACTS BUTTON
    @IBAction func addContactsSelected(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        _ = CNContactPickerViewController()
        let contactPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()
        contactPicker.displayedPropertyKeys = [CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]
        contactPicker.delegate = self

        contactPicker.predicateForSelectionOfContact = NSPredicate (value:false)
        contactPicker.predicateForSelectionOfProperty = NSPredicate(value: true)
        self.present(contactPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    //MARK -> WHEN A CONTACT IS SELECTED
    func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contactProperty: CNContactProperty) {

        let newitem = contactProperty.value as! CNPhoneNumber
        app.profile.contacts.append(newitem.stringValue)
        app.profile.saveToDefaults()
        tableView.reloadData()

    }

    //MARK -> TABLEVIEW
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return  app.profile.contacts.count

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")
        cell!.textLabel?.text = app.profile.contacts[indexPath.row]
        return cell!
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            app.profile.contacts.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            app.profile.saveToDefaults()
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .insert {

        }

    }
```

Comment: How is it "not working"? Wrong data, crash, ...? – You seem to assume that didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is called *before* viewDidLoad. That is not necessarily true, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32827625/viewcontrollers-viewdidload-called-before-appdelegates-method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not storing these values. You have set the delegates for those textfields, and you should implement some methods of UITextFieldDelegate. For example:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField == firstName {
        app.profile.firstName = textField.text
    } else if textField == lastName {
        app.profile.lastName = textField.text
    }
}
```

(https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619591-textfielddidendediting)

Please note, this will only store the value when the textfield finishes editing (for example, you tap on another textfield, and focus is moved to it). If you would like to store values whenever value changes, you could use either `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)` function of the delegate, or `UITextFieldTextDidChange` notification (https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619599-textfield and https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnotification.name/1619640-uitextfieldtextdidchange respectively)

Comment: Thanks it really helped!