# Firebase crashing randomly on launch

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, singleton

I have a firebase app in swift. Now my issue is very simple to explain but really weird to debug.

Issue:
Whenever I open the app, it works completely fine. Does everything it's supposed to etc. But when i just leave the app in background for a while and open it, I get a crash. I have to reopen it like 2 times for the crash to go or kill it.

Re-producing the error:
step 1: Open App (do something in there or just leave it) and then just go back to home and not kill it, keeping it in background

Step 2: Open the app after a while. --- > gives crash

Step 3: Open it again after step 2 after sometime or immediately --- > crashes again

Step 4: Open it the third time. ---> works totally fine.

Note: To escape the crashes I will always have to kill it. This overall is terrible UX.

Also, I have check with my plists. they are properly functioning. Yet when it crashes I get this error :

```
2018-12-20 19:05:44.272413-0800 SpotMi[15557:862318] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRAppNotConfigured', reason: 'Failed to get default Firebase Database instance. Must call `[FIRApp configure]` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) before using Firebase Database.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1a1e2bea0 0x1a0ffda40 0x1a1d32674 0x1030c8d20 0x102f9cd24 0x102f992b0                     0x102f9926c 0x10f928dc8 0x10f92ae28 0x10ef95e18 0x102f9935c 0x102f49644     0x102f4a55c 0x102f4ad94 0x102e03b18 0x102d5cd4c 0x102f49260 0x102f493b0 0x102f4ac74 0x102f4b11c 0x102dbaf3c 0x102dbafd8 0x1cea6620c 0x1cea6663c 0x1cf0551e4 0x1cf051200 0x1cf0240a0 0x1cf02585c 0x1cf02b2a8 0x1ce8c7358 0x1ce8cffd8 0x1ce8c6fd4 0x1ce8c7974 0x1ce8c5a74 0x1ce8c5720 0x1ce8ca8e0 0x1ce8cb840 0x1ce8ca798 0x1ce8cf684 0x1cf0297a0 0x1cec12bac 0x1a48609d4 0x1a486b79c 0x1a486ae94 0x10f928dc8 0x10f92ca10 0x1a489fa9c 0x1a489f728 0x1a489fd44 0x1a1dbc1cc 0x1a1dbc14c 0x1a1dbba30 0x1a1db68fc 0x1a1db61cc 0x1a402d584 0x1cf02d054 0x102d5da9c 0x1a1876bb4)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Appdelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    #if DEVELOPMENT
    print("Development Mode Started")
    let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info", ofType: "plist")
    guard let fileopts = FirebaseOptions.init(contentsOfFile: filePath!)
        else {
            fatalError("Couldn't load config file")
    }
    FirebaseApp.configure(options: fileopts)

    #else
    print("Production Mode Started")
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    #endif

    return true
}
```

I tried putting this patch in the `init()`, but then the notifications stops working.

How should I be tackling this issue. And what am i doing wrong?

Let me know if more info is required.

My firebase singleton is below:

```
class FBDataservice : NSObject {

static var ds = FBDataservice() //<-------- Always crahses on this line

let DB_URL: DatabaseReference = Database.database().reference()
let ST_URL: StorageReference = Storage.storage().reference()

private lazy var _REF_BASE = DB_URL
private lazy var _REF_POSTS = DB_URL.child("key1")
private lazy var _REF_USERS = DB_URL.child("key2")

private lazy var _ST_REF_PROFPOST = ST_URL.child("key3")

var REF_BASE: DatabaseReference! {
    return _REF_BASE
}

var REF_POSTS: DatabaseReference! {
    return _REF_POSTS
}

var REF_USERS: DatabaseReference! {
    return _REF_USERS
}

var REF_POST_USERIMG: StorageReference {
    return _ST_REF_USERPOST
}


}
```

Comment: look here https://medium.com/rocket-fuel/using-multiple-firebase-environments-in-ios-12b204cfa6c0

Comment: It seems like a race condition to me. While static fields are lazy initialized you may be accessing the `ds` before the `Firebase.configure()`. This happens if any of your initial view controllers (or each primary viewcontroller of a tab controller) uses the `ds` variable in their init() methods. Can you verify this?

Comment: As an addendum to my previous comment, please check if `ds` is called in any viewDidLoad() methods of the initial view controllers

Comment: @jms Hey, thanks for the response. yes I am calling ds in the viewDidLoad of init Controllers. But then I also want to start the app with the load itself. i cannot have the user signin everytime. So i keep a `authState` check in `appdelegate` and if the user is logged out, it'll just redirect to the signing page. What do you say about it?

Comment: @jms And if that was the case why does it fun on the third try. I am really unable to get it.

Comment: As I said, it could be a race condition. Whenever `FirebaseApp.configure()` completed before initial view controller initialization it will be fine. If not, then app will crash.

Comment: Yeah I totally get it. But, now what should I be doing in such case. Insert a delay ? Or something else?

Comment: To resolve this issue, remove the Main Interface from the project general settings. And initialize the correct storyboard after Firebase.configure() in the applicationDidFinishLaunching

Comment: What do you mean by main interface. i am sorry i dont follow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185590/discussion-between-jms-and-aakash-dave).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AppDelegate will initialize all initial view controllers (and all primary view controllers in a tab navigation controller) and call `viewDidLoad()` on them during app startup. This is by design ([viewController's viewdidload called before appDelegate's method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32827625/viewcontrollers-viewdidload-called-before-appdelegates-method))

The problem is accessing your `ds` variable in either init() or `viewDidLoad()` methods. This causes a race condition to occur between the call to `FirebaseApp.configure()` and each of the `viewDidLoad()` methods. If ever the `FirebaseApp.configure()` completes before the the viewcontroller initialization you will be fine.

To resolve this you need to take over storyboard initialization to yourself. This requires two steps:

1. Select your project in Xcode -> General. Scroll down to Main Interface and remove it
2. In your AppDelegate `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method initialize the required storyboard as follows:

   ```
   class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
       var window: UIWindow?
       func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

       // configure Firebase

       window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
       let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
       window?.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
       self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()        

       return true
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Hey I am having the same problem persisting even after what we had done. I really not quite sure about this one. Is there a work around

Comment: The correct answer to the question is given here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56324976/firebase-app-crashed-on-launch-when-made-active-from-background

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming it takes too long to connect to Firebase, so when a dependency in your code is meet, application does not know what to do. You can try to put connection-related codes (Firebase.configure) to a try-catch block to see what is going on.